# Where I can find some of this data bind in Ghost using handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I know my question seems weird but since I'm new when using ghost with handlebars language, I'm quite confused as to where I can find some of this data bind such as `title`, `@site.logo`, etc. I try to find it inside casper template but I still not find it, this is the example of the code image inside casper theme

[image: this is example inside of site-nav.hbs in casper template for ghost]

[image: this is example of post.hbs file for casper]

if you ask why I try to find it, I want to try add some of the content inside it or at least I want to take a look what kind of data bind that casper have or provided.

for example in this `post.hbs` you can see that there is a lot of data bind in here, but I just can't find what else the data bind they provided,

```
{{!< default}}

{{!-- The tag above means: insert everything in this file
into the {body} of the default.hbs template --}}

<header class="site-header">
    {{> site-header}}
</header>

{{!-- Everything inside the #post tags pulls data from the post --}}
{{#post}}

<main id="site-main" class="site-main outer">
    <div class="inner">

        <article class="post-full {{post_class}} {{#unless feature_image}}no-image{{/unless}}">

            <header class="post-full-header">

                {{#if primary_tag}}
                <section class="post-full-tags">
                    {{#primary_tag}}
                    <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
                    {{/primary_tag}}
                </section>
                {{/if}}

                <h1 class="post-full-title">{{title}}</h1>

                {{#if custom_excerpt}}
                <p class="post-full-custom-excerpt">{{custom_excerpt}}</p>
                {{/if}}

                <div class="post-full-byline">

                    <section class="post-full-byline-content">

                        <ul class="author-list">
                            {{#foreach authors}}
                            <li class="author-list-item">

                                <div class="author-card">
                                    {{#if profile_image}}
                                    <img class="author-profile-image" src="{{img_url profile_image size="xs"}}" alt="{{name}}" />
                                    {{else}}
                                    <div class="author-profile-image">{{> "icons/avatar"}}</div>
                                    {{/if}}
                                    <div class="author-info">
                                        {{#if bio}}
                                        <div class="bio">
                                            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
                                            <p>{{bio}}</p>
                                            <p><a href="{{url}}">More posts</a> by {{name}}.</p>
                                        </div>
                                        {{else}}
                                        <h2>{{name}}</h2>
                                        <p>Read <a href="{{url}}">more posts</a> by this author.</p>
                                        {{/if}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                {{#if profile_image}}
                                <a href="{{url}}" class="author-avatar">
                                    <img class="author-profile-image" src="{{img_url profile_image size="xs"}}" alt="{{name}}" />
                                </a>
                                {{else}}
                                <a href="{{url}}" class="author-avatar author-profile-image">{{> "icons/avatar"}}</a>
                                {{/if}}

                            </li>
                            {{/foreach}}
                        </ul>

                        <section class="post-full-byline-meta">
                            <h4 class="author-name">{{authors}}</h4>
                            <div class="byline-meta-content">
                                <time class="byline-meta-date" datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}">{{date format="D MMM YYYY"}}</time>
                                <span class="byline-reading-time"><span class="bull">&bull;</span> {{reading_time}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                    </section>


                </div>
            </header>

            {{#if feature_image}}
            <figure class="post-full-image">
                {{!-- This is a responsive image, it loads different sizes depending on device
                https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-guide-to-responsive-images-with-ready-to-use-templates-c400bd65c433 --}}
                <img
                    srcset="{{img_url feature_image size="s"}} 300w,
                            {{img_url feature_image size="m"}} 600w,
                            {{img_url feature_image size="l"}} 1000w,
                            {{img_url feature_image size="xl"}} 2000w"
                    sizes="(max-width: 800px) 400px,
                        (max-width: 1170px) 1170px,
                            2000px"
                    src="{{img_url feature_image size="xl"}}"
                    alt="{{title}}"
                />
            </figure>
            {{/if}}

            <section class="post-full-content">
                <div class="post-content">
                    {{content}}
                </div>
            </section>

            {{!-- Email subscribe form at the bottom of the page --}}
            {{#if @labs.members}}
                {{> subscribe-form}}
            {{/if}}

            {{!--
            <section class="post-full-comments">
                If you want to embed comments, this is a good place to do it!
            </section>
            --}}

        </article>

    </div>
</main>

{{!-- Links to Previous/Next posts --}}
<aside class="read-next outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="read-next-feed">
            {{#if primary_tag}}
            {{#get "posts" filter="tags:{{primary_tag.slug}}+id:-{{id}}" limit="3" as |related_posts|}}
                {{#if related_posts}}
                <article class="read-next-card">
                    <header class="read-next-card-header">
                        {{#../primary_tag}}
                        <h3><span>More in</span> <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a></h3>
                        {{/../primary_tag}}
                    </header>
                    <div class="read-next-card-content">
                        <ul>
                            {{#foreach related_posts}}
                            <li>
                                <h4><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></h4>
                                <div class="read-next-card-meta">
                                    <p><time datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}">{{date format="D MMM YYYY"}}</time> –
                                        {{reading_time}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            {{/foreach}}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="read-next-card-footer">
                        <a href="{{#../primary_tag}}{{url}}{{/../primary_tag}}">{{plural meta.pagination.total empty='No posts' singular='% post' plural='See all % posts'}}
                            →</a>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                {{/if}}
            {{/get}}
            {{/if}}

            {{!-- If there's a next post, display it using the same markup included from - partials/post-card.hbs --}}
            {{#next_post}}
                {{> "post-card"}}
            {{/next_post}}

            {{!-- If there's a previous post, display it using the same markup included from - partials/post-card.hbs --}}
            {{#prev_post}}
                {{> "post-card"}}
            {{/prev_post}}
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>

{{/post}}

{{!-- The #contentFor helper here will send everything inside it up to the matching #block helper found in default.hbs --}}
{{#contentFor "scripts"}}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // FitVids - start
        var $postContent = $(".post-full-content");
        $postContent.fitVids();
        // FitVids - end

        // Replace nav with title on scroll - start
        Casper.stickyNavTitle({
            navSelector: '.site-nav-main',
            titleSelector: '.post-full-title',
            activeClass: 'nav-post-title-active'
        });
        // Replace nav with title on scroll - end

        // Hover on avatar
        var hoverTimeout;
        $('.author-list-item').hover(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);

            $('.author-card').removeClass('hovered');
            $(this).children('.author-card').addClass('hovered');

        }, function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                $this.children('.author-card').removeClass('hovered');
            }, 800);
        });
    });
</script>
{{/contentFor}}
```

can someone help me to point it out where I can find a list of data bind they provided? I'm quite confused to understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they call that Helpers and you can find the full list here:
[Themes documentation](https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/)

There is several categories: Functionnal, Data, Utility, Extra... And you find several inside with a description for each.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a particular piece of data that you've put into Ghost admin? `{{@site.logo}}` and `{{@site.title}}` is how you out put those data values